# ErrorDocument 404 /404.html is not working in .htaccess file in APACHE

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, errordocument

mydomain.pe on a Linux server with Apache, I have added the following line `ErrorDocument 404 /404.html` in `.htaccess` under RewriteEngine on

However when doing a false url test: abc.mydomain.pe/etc.html throws me a 404 error by default.

My 404.html file is visible through the web in the url: abc.mydomain.pe/404.html

Please your support, I have time and I have not been able to solve it by my side.

That could be happening? I share my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html

RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.abc.mydomain.pe/$1 [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.abc.mydomain.pe$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.abc.mydomain.pe/$1 [L,R=301]

Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload"

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} libwww-perl.* 
RewriteRule .* ? [F,L]
Options -Indexes
</IfModule>


<IfModule mod_headers.c>
<FilesMatch ".(js|css|xml|gz|html)$">
Header append Vary: Accept-Encoding
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <filesMatch "\.(js|css|html|php)$">
        SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
    </filesMatch>
</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

## INICIO compresión gzip (mod_deflate)
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/shtml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
</IfModule> 
## FIN compresión gzip (mod_deflate)##

# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Configure el paquete “ea-php56” como el lenguaje de programación predeterminado “PHP”.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddType application/x-httpd-ea-php56 .php .php5 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Answer (score 1):

If your domain is mydomain.pe then your error document might be in the wrong place as you say it is in **abc.mydomain.pe/404.html**

Maybe you should copy the file 404.html to **mydomain.pe/404.html** because Apache will look for it there. It should be accessible via mydomain.pe/404.html not via abc.mydomain.pe/404.html

Comment: Thanks for your prompt response, the domain in use is abc.mydomain.pe (sub domain), but I also have the 404.html in mydomain.pe, this is visible by URL but is not loading when doing URL error testing.

I had also thought about it

Regards,
Axel P.

Answer (score 0):

I have been able to fix it by cPanel panel using "Error Pages", something curious, I noticed that a 404.shtml file ("s" added) was created, this is something new for me, maybe EasyApache 4 works now as well.

Thank you for reading,
Axel P.

Comment: I am answering several years too late, but I think that it depends on the sites-enabled/*.conf (which overrides the custom .htaccess): that one is the right place to put your custom ErrorDocument directive on Ubuntu distribution (OP doesn't mention hte distribution used)